# ASP.NET website displaying Windows Server IIS welcome page

Tags: iis

I have created a new asp.net website and hosted it in IIS in a web server and its opening correctly in the webserver in IE but when I open it in my local windows computer I am getting the IIS welcome page. I am not able to understand how to fix this issue. Can anyone give me some suggestions. Other websites from the same server are working correctly as expected.

similar problem:
http://techspeeder.com/2016/10/28/server-2016-anywhere-access-shows-iis-instead-of-login-page/

Comment: That really depends on how you've done the configuration, which you haven't described here at all.

Comment: Please tell me what all configuration settings you need

Comment: You'd need to show your IIS settings for the binding. Basically you need to prove that you've configured the correct site to display in IIS.

Comment: I gave the host name sampletest.com selected an ipaddress from the drop down and gave 80 as port number

Comment: Is sampletest.com set up to point to your machine? Do you have any other sites listening at port 80?

Comment: It is not setup to point to my machine, its on a windows server remote.

Comment: Okay, so you're not hosting on your machine, you're hosting it on a server and then trying to access it from your machine. Still, same question: do you have any other sites on that server listening at port 80?

Comment: yes all the websites hosted on that server on  are on port 80

Comment: And what host header is the default IIS site to listen for (the one that contains the welcome page)?

Comment: I didn't understand... Anything from web. Config

Comment: If you're seeing the welcome site, it's because you're hitting the IP address, port, and host name where the default IIS site (the one that displays the welcome page) is at. So it's up to you to figure out which site that is and get rid of it. And no, it's not in the web.config. Look in the IIS Manager.

Comment: Hey mason thanks for the suggestion. I removed the web site called default web site and now I am able to open the website in web server(remote IE) correctly but not from my local PC. Its giving me HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. Looking into how to fix that.

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Jexus Manager would tell you what are the requirements to access a site on IIS. Once you understand how site bindings work, such won't be questions any more.